# Products of simple $R$-modules are semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with identity element such that $R/J(R)$ is right Artinian. It is equivalent to say that $R$ is a semilical ring, i. e., $R$ has finitely many maximal right ideals. I want to know whether any direct product of simple $R$- modules is a semisimple module.
Thanks for any help or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but for trivial reasons.

The semisimple $R$ modules are in 1-1 correspondence with the semisimple $R/J(R)$ modules, which in this case are *all* $R/J(R)$ modules, since the ring is semisimple Artinian.

Therefore the product of simple modules - taken in $R$-mod - is exactly the same module as the one in $R/J(R)$-mod, and since it is semisimple there, it is semisimple in $R$-mod.

Comment: Worth noting that already for infinite products of vector spaces this is heavily dependent on the axiom of choice.